# Проблема со сменой кодировки на UTF-8 на LAMP

Tags: php, mysql, кодировка, utf-8, lamp

На Ubuntu 14.04 решил поставить LAMP (Apache2.4.7, php5.5.9, mysql5.5.44)
При попытке получить информацию из базы данных, все записи на кириллице выводятся как вопросительные знаки.

Запрос:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "pass", "db");
echo $mysqli->character_set_name();
```

Выдает: latin1

Проблему решает следующий метод:

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

Тогда соответственно все записи на кириллице корректно отображаются.
**НО**, как установить кодировку по умолчанию utf-8??

Mysql я так понял переключен:

```
mysql> show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like 'collation%';
+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_general_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

В phpinfo значение **default_charset** стоит *UTF-8*

В **/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/charset.conf** разкомментировал строку *AddDefaultCharset UTF-8*:

```
# Read the documentation before enabling AddDefaultCharset.
# In general, it is only a good idea if you know that all your files
# have this encoding. It will override any encoding given in the files
# in meta http-equiv or xml encoding tags.

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Ребутнул апач и mysql сервер, но проблема не решилась.Подскажите пожалуйста, уже всю голову сломал

Comment: Кодировку браузера смотрели? Другие русскоязычные тексты выводятся нормально?

Comment: Кодировка браузера также utf-8,и остальной русский текст (кроме того что берется из БД) выводится нормально

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6258048/2908793 - либо вызывать метод в рантайме, либо перекомпилировать. хз, почему в настройки не вынесли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос непонятен. 
Если речь о том, чтобы не писать вручную `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");`, то он неправильный. Писать надо. Это совсем нетрудно, и это единственный правильный способ задать кодировку клиента.

Comment: Я так понял с этим вообще заморачиватся не стоит? Просто ранее работал из-под Windows в OpenServer, и там сразу кодировка выставлялась utf8

Answer (score 0):

в [конфигурационном файле](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/mysql#%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0) можно указать [умолчательные настройки для клиентов](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-configuration.html):

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8
```

---

конфигурационный файл — скорее всего — `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, но точное имя и местоположение зависят от сборки `mysqld`.

---

**дополнение**

если предлагаемое изменение конфигурации не даст результата (после перезапуска *mysqld* и *http*-сервера), значит *mysqli* при установке соединения черпает информацию из какого-то другого источника и наиболее простым решением будет добавить после создания соединения вызов, рекомендованный в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/450948/178576).

Comment: mysql> show variables like 'char%' и так выдал, что для клиента стоит utf8

Comment: программу `mysql` вы ведь запускаете от имени не того же пользователя, от которого выполняется *php*-код. я обновил ответ.

Answer (score -1):

Убедитесь, что таблицы в базе данных имеют нужную кодировку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]